# Multidimensional ArrayList and Integer replacement

Tags: java, arrays, get, arraylist

What is the best *(or anyway, really)* of going through a bi-dimensional `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>` and for every `Int` that is equal to `1` you leave it, otherwise you subtract `1` from it. 
*i.e.* `if arrayList.get(i).get(j) == 3` it will now be `2` and so forth, but if it is `1` it stays `1`) Only in specific columns of the `ARRAYLIST<ARRAYLIST<INTEGER>>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get a shovel - there's just one way to do it.  Iterate over all the columns in all the rows:

```
// example declaration only - initially all zeros until you set them.
// assumes nrows and ncols are initialized and declared elsewhere
int [][] matrix = new int[nrows][ncols];
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; ++j) {
        // operate on the values here.
        if (matrix[i][j] != 1) {
            matrix[i][j] -= 1;
        }
    }
}
```

If you've got an List of List it looks like this:

```
List<List<Integer>> matrix = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
List<Integer> columnIdsToTransform = Arrays.asList({0, 4, 6 });
// You have to initialize the references; all are null right now.
for (List<Integer> row : matrix) {
    for (int j = 0; j < row.size(); ++j) {            
        // operate on the values here.
        value = row.get(j);
        if (columnsIdsToTransform.contains(j) && (value != 1)) {
            row.set(value-1, j);
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

Based on your edit, you should add an array or List of columns you want to perform this transformation on.  I've added an example to the second snippet.

Comment: Sorry duffymo just edited the question as I apparently had a brainfart when I posted it, thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through all the values and use your conditional statement for performing the operation on the `true` cases.

```
for (int i=0;i<Arraylist.size();i++) {
    for (int j=0;j<Arraylist[i].size();j++) {    
         if (arrayList.get(i).get(j) != 1) 
             arrayList.get(i).get(j) -= 1;         
    } 
}
```