# Java - Why do my arrays contain incorrect data

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing a program in Java in which I can find the transitive closure of a relation using Warshall's algorithm.  While I understand the algorithm I am new to java, and I am running into some odd behavior with arrays.

I am experiencing a few different behaviors.

One is (occasionally) when I change a value of an element in one array another array gets modified.  I've made the mistake before of not separating my declarations and initializations, so I am pretty sure that is not the case now.

Second,  Some times if I comment/uncomment `System.out.println()`'s all of my 2 dimensional arrays contain a value of '0', but if I revert the comment/uncomment I get values other than zero.  Most of the time the content I am printing to the screen is a hard-coded string, so I believe that should have no bearing on weather it is commented out or not (IE: Not a function call).

EDIT (Forgot to add the code):

Class:

```
package warshall;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Warshall {
    private int[][][] relation;
    public void setRelation(int[][][] relation){
        this.relation = relation;
    }  
    public void setRelationSet(int i, int j, int k, int value){
        this.relation[i][j][k] = value;
    } 
    public int[][][] getRelation(){
        return this.relation;
    }
    public int getRelationSet(int i, int j, int k){
        return this.relation[i][j][k];
    }

    private int size;
    public void setSize(int size){
        this.size = size;
    }    
    public int getSize(){
        return this.size;
    }

    private int[][] tempArray;


    public void process() {

        for(int k = 1; k < this.size; k++){
            tempArray = new int[this.size][this.size];

            for(int i = 0; i < this.size; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < this.size; j++){

                    for(int node = 0; node < k; node++){
                        if(this.relation[i][j][k-1] == 1 || (this.relation[i][node][k-1] == 1 && this.relation[node][j][k-1] == 1)){
                            System.out.println("i = "+i+": j = "+j+": k = "+k+": node = "+node);
                            tempArray[i][j] = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }   
            }

            System.out.println("Kth -1:");
            this.outputRelationSet(k-1);

            System.out.println("Kth: ");
            for(int m = 0; m < this.size; m++){
                for(int n = 0; n < this.size; n++){
                    this.relation[m][n][k] = tempArray[m][n];
                    //System.out.println(tempArray[m][n]);
                    if(n == this.size-1){
                        System.out.println("'"+tempArray[m][n]+"'");
                    }else{
                        System.out.print("'"+tempArray[m][n]+"'");
                    }

                }
            }

        }
    }

    public void outputRelationSet(int set){

        for (int i=0; i < this.size; i++){
            for(int j=0; j < this.size; j++){
                 if(j == this.size-1){
                    System.out.println("'"+this.relation[i][j][set]+"'");
                 }else{
                     System.out.print("'"+this.relation[i][j][set]+"'");
                 }
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

Main

```
package warshall;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int size = 4;
        int[][][] theArray = new int[size][size][size];

        for (int k=0; k < size; k++){
            for (int i=0; i < size; i++){
                for(int j=0; j < size; j++){
                    theArray[i][j][k] = 0;
                }
            }     
        }

        theArray[0][3][0] = 1;
        theArray[1][2][0] = 1;
        theArray[2][0][0] = 1;
        theArray[3][1][0] = 1;

        Warshall thisWarshall = new Warshall();
        thisWarshall.setSize(size);
        thisWarshall.setRelation(theArray);
        thisWarshall.outputRelationSet(0);
        System.out.println();

        thisWarshall.process();
        System.out.println("Final: ");
        thisWarshall.outputRelationSet(3);       
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:
To elaborate on item one.  In the Warshall.process() method when I hit this line `tempArray[i][j] = 1;` it seems to also change the associated value of the `Warshall.relation[i][j][k]` array.  What I am trying to do is use `tempArray[][]` to collect the results without modifying the `Warshall.relation[][][]` array which is what I am basing my calculations on.  Then finally after looping through all vertices I sync `tempArray[][]` with `Warshall.relation[][][k]`.  But because `Warshall.relation[i][j][k]` is being modified as I loop through the vertices my results are getting skewed.

To elaborate on item two.  I removed most of all `System.out.println()`'s which I was using for debugging so with the code posted I can not give a recreation of the issue.  I was more asking if there was a common reason for that behavior in Java.  When I get home I will get a portion of code together which recreates it and post another question specific to that issue.  I will add a link to it from this question for anyone who comes across in the future.

Comment: Your problem is still unclear. Where is the problem in your code?

Comment: This is how to create a multi dimensial `ArrayList` :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401850/how-to-create-a-multidimensional-arraylist-in-java

You can also see this example that handle integer ArrayList matrix :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089752/multidimensional-arraylist-and-integer-replacement

Comment: Please be more clear on your issue, eg. which array are you modifying and which gets changed? Which println() are you commenting/uncommenting?

Comment: I apologize for not providing this information in the first place.  It was late and I was very tired.  I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

For your second question.

No need of initializing each element of `int array` with `zero` because in `java` by default each element of `int array` is `zero`.

So if you do

```
int a[] = new Integer[5];// whether it is 1D , 2D or 3D
System.out.println(a[2]);
```

then this will print `0`